# Java, VS Code and packages

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package, classpath

I'm fairly n00bish at Java and am trying to get it set up with VS Code.

My $JAVA_HOME is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

When I make a new Java project the file structure is like this:

- bin
- src

  - app

    - App.java

This App.java file runs just fine if I press 'run' (the VS Code plugins take care of this).

However, if I make a new package, and make the file structure look like this:

- bin
- src

  - app

    - App.java
  - test

    - Test.java

and then do a simple system out in the main method in the Test class, and press 'run', the file fails to compile. There are no problems in the 'problems' panel, so I think my hazy understanding of the Java classpath (and of Java package management generally) might be the issue. Might anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is `app` a source folder or a package? Asked another way, does `App.java` start with a `package app;` statement? If yes, them `app` is a package. If no, then `app` is a source folder, i.e. a folder that is the root of source files, in which case you need to make sure `test` is also a source folder, not just a regular folder on the file system.

Comment: Hi Andreas, app is a package, but VS Code can't seem to find the class

Comment: what's your java_home in settings.json ?